# Why I must use "new" while creating object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need some help can someone explain me why I mmust use new while creating an object?

I created some objet like this:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "Danny",
    lastName: "Black",
    age: 20,
    display: function(){
        document.write("My name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " and my age is " + this.age);
    }
}

var example = new person.display();
document.getElementById("firstObject").innerHTML = example;
```

and than like this:

```
var anotherExample = new person.display();
document.getElementById("firstObject").innerHTML = anotherExample;
```

what is difference?

Comment: Calling `new` there doesn't really make any sense. Nobody said you have to use `new`, heck the `person` object you created was not created via `new`.

Comment: You don't need `new` to create an object in js. `var x = {a: 2}` is an object, but it doesn't require any special keyword

Comment: Yeah, you're skipping the biggest reason to use `new` (non-shared state)

Comment: @CristianTraìna the example isn't calling `new` on an object

Comment: [See here for a little information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: ok, lets say I created object without using NEW what the difference ?